# The best way to Fetch counts of depending entities in JPA

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

This question is actually for design suggestion.

**Situation:** I have a table `Feed` which contains feeds details like description date of creation, feed owner etc etc. I have two associated tables with feed "Likes", "Comments". Likes contains mapping of feed and user who liked feed, comments contains comment along with feedId and userId

I have to fetch Feed details of a particular feed along with below details:

1. Number of likes
2. Number of Comments
3. Whether User who requested feed details has liked feed or not

I have two ways to implement this but not sure which one is better with JPA and why or is there any other way

**Solution 1:**

I fetch feed details using a stored procedure which will take feedId and userId and will return feed details along with other data. As it will include more than one query, hence using the stored procedure, I can get all data in single call to database

**Solution 2:**

I fetch `Feed` details using `entityManager.find()` and use criteria to find count of likes, comment and whether user has liked feed or not. This will require 4 calls to the database.

If I fetch complete Feed object and fetch likers ugin feed.getLikers() and populate count and check liked by user then it might be costly if likers are in huge number.

I don't think using a stored procedure is good option when I'm using any ORM (JPA here) it will simply give me List which is not an entity (correct me if I'm wrong). Making 4 calls to populate entire entity is not good solution either.

Please suggest the best way to solve this.

Just for info and if required: I am using JPA with Spring boot

Comment: You can just use a query to count the likers, instead of loading them all. Do what seems simple and reasonable (loading all the likers just to count them doesn't count as reasonable), and it will probably be fast enough. Optimize if you prove this causes a performance problem.

Comment: Sorry if the question is misleading, I don't just need the count, i need feed details along with counts. So if i use queries, i'll have to fire 4 queries to populate feed. I have assigned lazy loading for likers so i won't be fetching likers instantaneously

Comment: I understand that. My point is that if sending 4 queries is fast enough, and makes your code simple, readable and maintainable, there's no reason to choose another strategy. Keep it simple, and optimize if necessary only.